# Pandas assign the groupby sum value to the last row in the original table

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, sum

For example, I have a table

A

```
id  price sum
1     2    0
1     6    0
1     4    0
2     2    0
2     10   0
2     1    0
2     5    0
3     1    0
3     5    0
```

What I want is like (the last row of `sum` should be the sum of `price` of a group)

```
id  price sum
1     2    0
1     6    0
1     4    12
2     2    0
2     10   0
2     1    0
2     5    18
3     1    0
3     5    6
```

What I can do is find out the sum  using

```
A['price'].groupby(A['id']).transform('sum')
```

However I don't know how to assign this to the `sum` column (last row).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `last_valid_index` to locate rows to fill

```
g = df.groupby('id')
l = pd.DataFrame.last_valid_index
df.loc[g.apply(l), 'sum'] = g.price.sum().values
df

   id  price  sum
0   1      2    0
1   1      6    0
2   1      4   12
3   2      2    0
4   2     10    0
5   2      1    0
6   2      5   18
7   3      1    0
8   3      5    6
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
df.assign(sum=df.groupby('id')['price'].transform('sum').drop_duplicates(keep='last')).fillna(0)
```

OR

```
df['sum'] = (df.groupby('id')['price']
               .transform('sum')
               .mask(df.id.duplicated(keep='last'), 0))
```

Output:

```
   id  price   sum
0   1      2   0.0
1   1      6   0.0
2   1      4  12.0
3   2      2   0.0
4   2     10   0.0
5   2      1   0.0
6   2      5  18.0
7   3      1   0.0
8   3      5   6.0
```