# pandas groupby and subtract last value of one columns with first value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to add a new column that contains the difference between the first value of one column and last value of another column
I am using this command

```
df['diff']=df.groupby(['T_Id'])['EndMeterReading'].max()-df['StartMeterReading'].min()
```

But its filling new column with `NaN`

how can I achieve my desired result.

Original DataFrame

```
+------+-------+--------------+------------+
| D_Id | T_Id  | StartReading | EndReading |
+------+-------+--------------+------------+
|    1 | 4716a |      4323.17 |     4324.8 |
|    1 | 4716a |      4324.96 |    4325.34 |
|    1 | 4716a |      4326.47 |    4327.22 |
|    1 | 4716a |       4327.4 |    4328.43 |
|    1 | 4716a |      4328.85 |    4330.73 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4346.65 |    4347.62 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4347.67 |    4349.88 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4351.62 |    4351.83 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4352.88 |    4354.32 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4354.93 |    4355.14 |
|    1 | 4716b |       4355.2 |    4355.82 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4356.91 |    4357.37 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4357.74 |    4358.26 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4359.89 |    4360.46 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4360.61 |    4361.43 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4361.47 |    4362.11 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4362.88 |    4368.49 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4368.94 |    4369.78 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4370.91 |    4371.25 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4372.67 |    4372.77 |
+------+-------+--------------+------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+------+-------+--------------+------------+------------------+
| D_Id | T_Id  | StartReading | EndReading |       Diff       |
+------+-------+--------------+------------+------------------+
|    1 | 4716a |      4323.17 |     4324.8 |             7.56 |
|    1 | 4716a |      4324.96 |    4325.34 |             7.56 |
|    1 | 4716a |      4326.47 |    4327.22 |             7.56 |
|    1 | 4716a |       4327.4 |    4328.43 |             7.56 |
|    1 | 4716a |      4328.85 |    4330.73 |             7.56 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4346.65 |    4347.62 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4347.67 |    4349.88 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4351.62 |    4351.83 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4352.88 |    4354.32 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4354.93 |    4355.14 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |       4355.2 |    4355.82 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4356.91 |    4357.37 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4357.74 |    4358.26 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4359.89 |    4360.46 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4360.61 |    4361.43 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4361.47 |    4362.11 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4362.88 |    4368.49 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4368.94 |    4369.78 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4370.91 |    4371.25 |            26.12 |
|    1 | 4716b |      4372.67 |    4372.77 |            26.12 |
+------+-------+--------------+------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `max` and `min` function for `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame`, so possible subtracting correctly:

```
df['diff']= (df.groupby('T_Id')['EndReading'].transform('max')-
             df.groupby('T_Id')['StartReading'].transform('min'))

print (df)
    D_Id   T_Id  StartReading  EndReading   diff
0      1  4716a       4323.17     4324.80   7.56
1      1  4716a       4324.96     4325.34   7.56
2      1  4716a       4326.47     4327.22   7.56
3      1  4716a       4327.40     4328.43   7.56
4      1  4716a       4328.85     4330.73   7.56
5      1  4716b       4346.65     4347.62  26.12
6      1  4716b       4347.67     4349.88  26.12
7      1  4716b       4351.62     4351.83  26.12
8      1  4716b       4352.88     4354.32  26.12
9      1  4716b       4354.93     4355.14  26.12
10     1  4716b       4355.20     4355.82  26.12
11     1  4716b       4356.91     4357.37  26.12
12     1  4716b       4357.74     4358.26  26.12
13     1  4716b       4359.89     4360.46  26.12
14     1  4716b       4360.61     4361.43  26.12
15     1  4716b       4361.47     4362.11  26.12
16     1  4716b       4362.88     4368.49  26.12
17     1  4716b       4368.94     4369.78  26.12
18     1  4716b       4370.91     4371.25  26.12
19     1  4716b       4372.67     4372.77  26.12
```

Comment: can you please tell how can i add a new column to the above df with all nulls except the last occurrence/row of group like 0 or 1

Comment: @M_S_N - what is index of new column filled by `1` and what filled by `0` ?

Comment: like fill first occurrence of 4716a with 0,0,0,0 but last occurrence has 1 in a new column

Comment: @M_S_N so index `0` and `5` is `1` and all another values are `0` on new column?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49018709/8117999   similar to this except for sum just need 1

Comment: @M_S_N - Can you check `df['new'] = (~df['T_Id'].duplicated(keep='last')).astype(int)` ?

Answer (score 0):

find `first` and `last` using `groupby`, then `merge` back to original df

```py
df2 = df.groupby(['T_Id']).agg({'StartReading' : 'first', 'EndReading' : 'last'}).reset_index(0)
df2['Diff'] = df2['EndReading'] - df2['StartReading']
df.merge(df2[['T_Id', 'Diff']], how='left', on='T_Id')
```