# Subtract last timestamp from first timestamp for each Id in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, subtraction

I have a dataframe (df) with the following structure:

| retweet_datetime | tweet_id | tweet_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-24 03:33:15 | 85053699 | 2020-04-24 02:28:22 |
| 2020-04-24 02:43:35 | 85053699 | 2020-04-24 02:28:22 |
| 2020-04-18 04:24:03 | 86095361 | 2020-04-18 00:06:01 |
| 2020-04-18 00:19:08 | 86095361 | 2020-04-18 00:06:01 |
| 2020-04-18 00:18:38 | 86095361 | 2020-04-18 00:06:01 |
| 2020-04-18 00:07:08 | 86095361 | 2020-04-18 00:06:01 |

The retweet_datetime is sorted from latest to newest retweets.

I'd like to create two new columns as follows:

1. `tweet_lifetime1`: the difference between the last retweet time and the first retweet time, i.e., for each tweet_id: last retweet_datetime  - first retweet_datetime
2. `tweet_lifetime2`: the difference between the last retweet time and tweet creation time (`tweet_datetime`)

### Update

For example, for the tweet id: **"86095361"**:

- `tweet_lifetime1` =  `2020-04-18 04:24:03 - 2020-04-18 00:07:08` (`04:16:55`)
- `tweet_lifetime2` = `2020-04-18 04:24:03 - 2020-04-18 00:06:01` (`04:18:02`)

The expected output df:

| retweet_datetime | tweet_id | tweet_datetime | lifetime1 | lifetime2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-24 03:33:15 | 85053699 | 2020-04-24 02:28:22 | 00:49:40 | 01:04:53 |
| 2020-04-18 04:24:03 | 86095361 | 2020-04-18 00:06:01 | 04:16:55 | 04:18:02 |

I've seen several similar posts, but they mostly subtract consecutive rows. For example, I can subtract the time difference between each retweet_datetimes for each tweet id as follows:

```
df2 = df.assign(delta = df.groupby('tweet_id')['retweet_datetime'].diff())
```

Comment: Check out: [pandas groupby and subtract last value of one columns with first value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59190660/pandas-groupby-and-subtract-last-value-of-one-columns-with-first-value-of-anothe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) with subtract column with [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html), [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is used for drop column `tmp` after processing:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('tweet_id', as_index=False)
         .agg(retweet_datetime=('retweet_datetime','first'),
              tmp = ('retweet_datetime','last'),
              tweet_datetime = ('tweet_datetime','last')))

df1['lifetime1'] = df1['retweet_datetime'].sub(df1.pop('tmp'))
df1['lifetime2'] = df1['retweet_datetime'].sub(df1['tweet_datetime'])
print (df1)
   tweet_id    retweet_datetime      tweet_datetime       lifetime1  \
0  85053699 2020-04-24 03:33:15 2020-04-24 02:28:22 0 days 00:49:40   
1  86095361 2020-04-18 04:24:03 2020-04-18 00:06:01 0 days 04:16:55   

        lifetime2  
0 0 days 01:04:53  
1 0 days 04:18:02
```

If need format `HH:MM:SS` use:

```
def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))

df1['lifetime1'] = df1['retweet_datetime'].sub(df1.pop('tmp')).apply(f)
df1['lifetime2'] = df1['retweet_datetime'].sub(df1['tweet_datetime']).apply(f)
print (df1)
   tweet_id    retweet_datetime      tweet_datetime lifetime1 lifetime2
0  85053699 2020-04-24 03:33:15 2020-04-24 02:28:22  00:49:40  01:04:53
1  86095361 2020-04-18 04:24:03 2020-04-18 00:06:01  04:16:55  04:18:02
```

Answer (score 3):

Groupby and agg with `first` to select the first row per group, then groupby and agg `retweet_datetime` with `last` to select last value per group. Then `join` aggregated dataframes and calculate `lifetime1` and `lifetime2` by subtracting relevant columns

```
g = df.groupby('tweet_id')
s = g.first().join(g['retweet_datetime'].agg(['last']))

s['lifetime1'] = s['retweet_datetime'] - s.pop('last')
s['lifetime2'] = s['retweet_datetime'] - s['tweet_datetime']
```

---

```
            retweet_datetime      tweet_datetime       lifetime1       lifetime2
tweet_id                                                                        
85053699 2020-04-24 03:33:15 2020-04-24 02:28:22 0 days 00:49:40 0 days 01:04:53
86095361 2020-04-18 04:24:03 2020-04-18 00:06:01 0 days 04:16:55 0 days 04:18:02
```